# How to put the current date in the footer of every page

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, geometry, date, scrartcl

My document class is scrartcl and I defined the pagemargins with `geometry` as follows

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=1cm, bottom=2cm, a4paper, twoside]{geometry}
```

So the page numbers are in the corners of the pages. I want to put the current date with a preceding text somewhere above the page numbers maybe next to them. I don't know, whatever works at all and looks better. It should be just like this:

```
Stand: 27.05.2021
```

I read that `fancyhdr` should not be used with `scrartcl`, so I don't really know how to handle footers with koma script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `scrlayer-scrpage` package in this kind of situation (essentially it replaces `fancyhdr` for KOMA script classes)

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=1cm, bottom=2cm, a4paper, twoside]{geometry} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\lofoot{\upshape Stand: \today}
\begin{document}
    Inhalt...
\end{document}
```

Where `upshape` makes sure it is not in italics and `babel` ensures the date is typeset in German rather than US american.

If, like you asked, the date should be above the pagenumber, you can do this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=1cm, bottom=2.5cm, a4paper, twoside]{geometry} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\rofoot{\upshape Stand: \today \\ \thepage}
\begin{document}
    Inhalt...
\end{document}
```

Note that in this case, your bottom margin was to small and I added .5cm.

For more information on this package, read chapter 5 of the [KOMA-manual](https://mirror.clientvps.com/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide.pdf), which explains all of the options.

Comment: This does not put the date on every page though, only the last page has it. Could it be because I am using `xltabular`, which stretches a table over several pages? Actually my whole document is a single very long table.

Comment: You are right, `\lofoot` will only affect every other page. Try `\ofoot` instead. You may need to define empty footers first or the page number may be displayed twice.

Comment: That works! It was actually the `twoside` option which put the `\lofoot` date  on the odd pages only.